# i am learning selenium by my own. I have the following question from an interview. write an xpath using sibling

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have the following question from an interview: Write an xpath to access the hotels link by traversing from flights link:
[image]

i have highlighted the flights link in web browsertool. but how to do after that i am not sure

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: i tried //span[contains(@class,'chFlights')]//following-sibling::span(@class='chHotle')

Comment: @JeyanthiRanjit I see this is a public site. can you share a link to that page?

Comment: //li[data-cy='menu_Flights']/a[contains(@href, "makemytrip")]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this **HTML:**

```
<ul class="makeFlex font12">
   <li data-cy="menu_Flights" class="menu_Flights">
      <a href="https://www.makemytrip.com/flights/" class="active makeFlex hrtlCenter column
         ">
         <span class="chNavIcon appendBottom2 chSprite chFlights active"></span>
         <span class="false chNavText darkGreyText">
            <!-- --> <!-- -->Flights 
         </span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li data-cy="menu_Hotels" class="menu_Hotels">
      <a href="https://www.makemytrip.com/hotels/" class="makeFlex hrtlCenter column">
         <span class="chNavIcon appendBottom2 chSprite chHotels"></span>
         <span class="false chNavText darkGreyText">
            <!-- --> <!-- -->Hotels 
         </span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li data-cy="menu_Homestays" class="menu_Homestays">
      <a href="https://www.makemytrip.com/homestays/" class="makeFlex hrtlCenter column">
         <span class="chNavIcon appendBottom2 chSprite chHomestays"></span>
         <span class="false chNavText darkGreyText">
            <!-- --> <!-- -->Homestays 
         </span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li data-cy="menu_Holidays" class="removeItemMargin menu_Holidays">
      <a href="https://www.makemytrip.com/holidays-india/" class="makeFlex hrtlCenter column">
         <span class="chNavIcon appendBottom2 chSprite chHolidays"></span>
         <span class="false chNavText darkGreyText">
            <!-- --> <!-- -->Holiday Packages 
         </span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li data-cy="menu_Trains" class="menu_Trains">
      <a href="https://www.makemytrip.com/railways/" class="makeFlex hrtlCenter column">
         <span class="chNavIcon appendBottom2 chSprite chTrains"></span>
         <span class="false chNavText darkGreyText">
            <!-- --> <!-- -->Trains 
         </span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li data-cy="menu_Buses" class="menu_Buses">
      <a href="https://www.makemytrip.com/bus-tickets/" class="makeFlex hrtlCenter column">
         <span class="chNavIcon appendBottom2 chSprite chBuses"></span>
         <span class="false chNavText darkGreyText">
            <!-- --> <!-- -->Buses 
         </span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li data-cy="menu_Cabs" class="menu_Cabs">
      <a href="https://www.makemytrip.com/cabs/" class="makeFlex hrtlCenter column">
         <span class="chNavIcon appendBottom2 chSprite chCabs"></span>
         <span class="false chNavText darkGreyText">
            <!-- --> <!-- -->Cabs 
         </span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li data-cy="menu_Visa" class="menu_Visa">
      <a href="https://www.makemytrip.com/visa/" class="makeFlex hrtlCenter column">
         <span class="chNavIcon appendBottom2 chSprite chVisa"></span>
         <span class="false chNavText darkGreyText">
            <!-- --> <!-- -->Visa 
         </span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li data-cy="menu_Charters" class="menu_Charters">
      <a href="https://www.makemytrip.com/charter-flights/" class="makeFlex hrtlCenter column">
         <span class="chNavIcon appendBottom2 chSprite chCharterFlights"></span>
         <span class="reduceMenuSpacing chNavText darkGreyText">
            <!-- --> <!-- -->Charter Flights 
         </span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li data-cy="menu_Activities" class="menu_Activities">
      <a href="https://www.makemytrip.com/activities/" class="makeFlex hrtlCenter column">
         <span class="chNavIcon appendBottom2 chSprite chActivities"></span>
         <span class="false chNavText darkGreyText">
            <!-- --> <!-- -->Activities 
         </span>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**A simple xpath** to access the `hotels link` by traversing from `flights link`:

```
//a[contains(@href,'/flights/')]/../following-sibling::li
```

**Explanation:**

```
//a[contains(@href,'/flights/')]
```

is to target `flights` and then go step up in DOM by using `/..` and the looking for `following-sibling` which is `li`

Comment: Thank you. Little correction worked - //a[contains(@href,'/flights/')]/../following-sibling::li[contains(@class,'Hotels')]